# Run openvpn without GUI in the client mode

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

I need to run my openvpn binary file in the client mode from the command line or something (maybe from a python script) supplying it with location of the client.ovpn file, then connect to a server and then later **properly** disconnect. Of course, I don't need its GUI to be shown.

How can I do that?

I need to do it on Windows at the moment if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN provide a `Windows Service` for exactly [this](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#startup) requirement.  Open your computer management services windows and enable the `openvpnservice` .. This will auto start **all** openvpn config files in `..\openvpn\config` directory.

Comment: and how to disconnect?

Comment: and I don't want to auto start all openvpn conf files, reread my question.

Comment: To stop `openvpn` you can simply stop the `openvpnservice` and this will exit all open configs. Rewrite your question to explain the specific problem.

Comment: the question is to run it, but not autorun it on windows boot.

Comment: I don't need to stop all open config. I want to be able to run and stop openvpn with one specific config at any given time.

Comment: You can create a batch file to start and stop the `openvpnservice` and have only one configuration file in the `openvpn\config` directory.  If you require multiple configs rewrite your question to **clearly** explain what you need.

Comment: I'm saying again: run and close openvpn multiple time with different config file which may or may not be the "config" directory.

Answer (score -1):

https://openvpn.net/community-resources/running-openvpn-from-a-console-window/

```
  openvpn --config sample.ovpn
```

try this